# How to prevent a child div to overflow its parent if child is set position fixed

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a child fixed to the body at a certain position but not allow it to overflow its parent div.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.parent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 3em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: .4em .7em;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>child</div>
</div>
```

here is the running codepen for this example - https://codepen.io/kartikth40/pen/xxmKRLV?editors=1100

If you scroll down the page in this example the child element will stick to the window but I wanted it to not overflow the parent(orange div).

Comment: `position: fixed` will move an element completely out of the flow and purely position it relative to the viewport. It is intended to leave the parent element as it then should be an element at a fixed position that no longer cares where the parent element is. IF you want to keep an element within the parent, you either need to use `position: absolute` or `position: sticky` depending on the use-case

Comment: @tacoshy what if I wanted to stick the child to the window but wanted it to not overflow its parent, isn't there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: @FaeghehMohammadian What do those links suppose to answer? Completely unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is the usage of `position: sticky`in your case. You have to remove `.parent {position: relative; overflow: hidden; }`:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.parent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
}

.child {
  position: sticky;
  top: 45vh;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 3em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: .4em .7em;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>child</div>
</div>
```

`position: sticky` is a combination of `position: static` and `position: fixed`.
The element will remain static until the declared top/right/bottom/left position has been reached. At that point, it will be sticky (`position: fixed`) and remain at that position relative to the viewport. The main difference is, that the element is not completely removed out of flow. That means, the element remains a child element of the parent and will leave the viewport as soon as the parent levels the screen.

What I also removed where `left: 40%` which you only used to center the element. However, that method does not work with position: sticky and is only a pure guess that is not very responsive. To center a block element you can give it a specific width (smaller then the parent element)and then center it with `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Oh wow it works! Can you explain it briefly though ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with JS:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
const child = document.querySelector('.child');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  const childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();

  const maxTop = parentRect.bottom - childRect.height;
  const minTop = parentRect.top;
  
  let newTop = window.scrollY + parentRect.height * 0.45;

  newTop = Math.min(newTop, maxTop);
  newTop = Math.max(newTop, minTop);
  
  child.style.top = newTop + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.parent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 3em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: .4em .7em;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>child</div>
</div>
```

This JavaScript code tracks when a user scrolls the page.

It calculates the positions of the parent and child elements on the screen.
As the user scrolls, the child element's position is adjusted to stay within its parent's boundaries using the calculated values.

This way, the child element appears fixed to the screen but constrained within its parent's dimensions.

Comment: It works perfectly. However, I think it is a modern front-end disease to use JS for something that basic CSS (not a CSS hack) can do by default. It also is not in compliance with basic maintenance conventions. Apply declarations or functionality in only one spot so you only need to change it in one spot. IF you want to remove the function, you first search the CSS and realize that the style changes are not applied there and then need to look into JS and see what emulates `position: sticky`

Comment: I agree with you wholeheartedly. I am also more of a fan of your solution.